WP dynamic block - change content without saving
I have a WordPress plugin containing a dynamic Gutenberg block which returns a div on the front-end:
register_block_type(
  PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'dist/my-plugin/block.json',
    array(
      'render_callback' => array( $this, 'render_my_plugin_block' ),
    )
  PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'dist/my-plugin/block.json'
);

Old end result:
<div class="my-plugin-block"></div>

I am targeting this div with React and populating its contents. Now In a new version I am using InnerBlocks on the save function as opposed to returning null.
export default function Save() {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <InnerBlocks.Content />
        </div>
    );
}

Which produces the following new end result:
<div class="my-plugin-container">
  <div class="my-plugin-section-1"></div>
  <div class="my-plugin-section-2"></div>
  <div class="my-plugin-section-3"></div>
</div>

I have written a deprecation which fixes this on the editor and once a user saves the post. But this only works until the user saves the post. Is there any way to change all those instances to the new HTML markup without relying on a manual save?
So make old become the new end result without relying on a manual save.

what's the difference between <div class="my-plugin-block"> and your new block version with no child blocks? I don't see any deprecation code in your question or details of the problem you were trying to solve, the context is super helpful if not essential. Wether changing those instances can be done will depend a lot on what the difference between the rendered markup and the new system looks like, examples of the two side by side equivalents will be needed

I am sorry you're right, I have added more information.
